# Remove a property from a component on condition, reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to remove a property all together based on condition? It's external package so I cant just pass `null` to the property.

```
const enabledSelectedRow = false

<BootstrapTable
        selectRow={ selectRow } // remove selectedRow if enabledSelectRow === false
        bootstrap4
        bordered={false}
    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, if `=== false` we spread an empty object

```
const enabledSelectedRow = false

<BootstrapTable
   {...(enabledSelectRow === false ? {} : {selectRow: selectRow} )}  // remove selectedRow if enabledSelectRow === false
   bootstrap4
   bordered={false}
/>
```